# composer and nodejs on same server

Tags: node.js, nginx, composer-php, apache2

So I want to run composer and nodejs on same website. Is it good practice? How I should deal with environment and file structures?

Answer (score 0):

No problem: It will work very well, but it needs to be set to a different port. For example: apache2 is using port 80. And NodeJs will use the port that you set.